# How do I set up a Virtual Host on CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to use the "virtual host" feature of CouchDB to keep separate databases for host domains. The platform is a RHEL (Linux) virtual server.

I have created a working C-Name for testing, I have edited the [vhosts] section of ***local.ini***, and I can successfully load both the JSON service and Fauxton through the new domain. However, the new, separate database does not appear to be accessible.

Unable to find any other instruction, I **duplicated** and renamed the **existing database** at /var/lib/couchdb, and created a matching symlink in /opt/couchdb. ...but the database(s) can't be found.

> {"error":"not_found","reason":"Database does not exist."}

Ownership of the new database is the same as the original. The new symlink is traversable via shell. I have tried various paths & path formats to the database in the [vhost] section of local.ini, including bypassing the symlink. The original parallel set up is still functional.

EDIT: Pointing the new domain to the original database doesn't work either.

Can someone shed some wisdom?

**local.ini**

```
[vhosts]
;example.com = /database/
test.suncourier.com:5984 = /data_suncourier/
```

**/opt/couchdb/**

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 couchdb couchdb     16 Aug 19 12:40 data -> /var/lib/couchdb
lrwxrwxrwx  1 couchdb couchdb     27 Oct 24 14:11 data_suncourier -> /var/lib/couchdb_suncourier
```

**/var/lib/**

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 couchdb couchdb 4096 Oct 21 10:49 couchdb
drwxr-xr-x  7 couchdb couchdb 4096 Oct 21 10:49 couchdb_suncourier
```

Comment: 1/ Did you create the database through couchdb's api?
curl -XPUT http://localhost:5984/data_suncourier
2/ If you make modification "manually" (*.ini file and not with fauxton), you have to restart couchdb. The config files are only read once at boot.

Comment: I have tried so many configuration changes, restarting every time, as I would any other. I have learned a lot since posting this question, but I still haven't been able to "get CouchDB running" in a virtual host configuration. How do I set up the initial database files?

Comment: I can see that on test.suncourier.com:5984/_all_dbs there are 2 dbs (testdata and inventory). Just set "sata_suncourier" the same way, something like "curl -XPUT https://admin:password@test.suncourier.com:5984/data_suncourier". If the Database doesn't exist, no wonder you get a 

    {"error":"not_found","reason":"Database does not exist."}

Comment: A virtual host is not currently configured because I can't get it to work.